# Unexpected abort using GtkTextBuffer

Tags: c, gtk

I am developing a Gtk based application where I need to update every X seconds a GtkTextBuffer, by concatenating the text that is already there. Apparently it succeeds but sometimes "randomly" the application aborts and I assume that it is due to this element, as it wasn't happening before. It sometimes aborts when there is a second/third update (each update only adds one new line) and sometimes it does not abort at all. I have based the TextBuffer update function on simple chat applications behavior but I don't know what I am doing wrong. The update function is:

```
void updateTextWindow(char *new_msg){
    g_print("Msg rcv: %s\n", new_msg);
    GtkTextIter start, end;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (global_text_window);
    //global_text_window is a global gtkwidget where TextBuffer is embedded
    gchar *previous_text;

    gtk_text_buffer_get_bounds (buffer, &start, &end);
    previous_text = gtk_text_buffer_get_text (buffer, &start, &end, FALSE);

    strcat(previous_text, "\n");
    strcat(previous_text, new_msg);

    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, previous_text, -1);

    g_free(previous_text);
}
```

Moreover the related code in the main function where all GtkWidgets are declared and initializated is:

```
void create_ui (CustomData *data) {

    [...]

    GtkWidget *secondary_box; /* for text entry & buffer */
    GtkScrolledWindow *scrolling_box;
    GtkWidget *text_window;
    GtkTextBuffer *buffer;
    GtkWidget *text_entry;

    secondary_box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 1);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(secondary_box, 600, -1);
    scrolling_box = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(scrolling_box, GTK_POLICY_NEVER, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
    text_entry = gtk_entry_new();
    global_text_entry = text_entry;
    gtk_entry_set_max_length(text_entry, 25);

    text_window = gtk_text_view_new();
    buffer = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(text_window));
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buffer, "\n", -1);
    gtk_text_view_set_editable(text_window, FALSE);
    global_text_window = text_window;
    gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport(scrolling_box, text_window);

    gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_CONTAINER(secondary_box), text_entry, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(text_entry), "activate", G_CALLBACK(text_entry_cb), &data);
    gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_CONTAINER(secondary_box), scrolling_box, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    [...]
}
```

The update function is called from another thread, not from the "activate" callback for the text entry widget.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code doesn't make sense. You're concatenating into a string that doesn't have space to hold more text, that's undefined behavior waiting to happen! Your posted answer doesn't make sense either, there's no point in creating a copy of the text like that. That might help just because it uses the heap a bit more, so perhaps you get luckier. Still undefined behavior to concatenate into `previous_text`.

If you want to append more text, there's no need to re-set the entire text contents. Just use [`gtk_text_buffer_insert()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-insert) to insert new text at the end. Use [`gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-get-iter-at-offset) first to get an iterator for the end of the buffer's contents.

**UPDATE** Oh, and also, you absolutely *cannot* call GTK+ from multiple threads. It is not a thread-safe library, so don't do that. It's a bit unclear if you do, but it sure sounds like it.

Comment: You forgot to talk about the other part of the reason the code crashes: GTK+ is not thread-safe; all adjustments to the GtkTextBuffer must be made on the main thread, using `gdk_threads_add_idle()` to schedule main thread actions.

Comment: @andlabs Thanks, fixed.